# Given that Classes have been introduced, why would someone still use `let xyz = new Object()` today?

Tags: javascript, class, object, ecmascript-6

Plenty of articles on the internet still teach how to create objects in the following manner.

```
let car = new Object();
car.make = 'Ford';
car.model = 'Mustang';
car.year = 1969;
```

However, with the introduction of Classes in ES6, as in the following.

```
class Car {
    constructor(make, model, year) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

What purpose does a JavaScript Object serve now? Is `let xyz = new Object()` still necessary?

### Note

Most of the other "similar" answers were written before Classes were introduced. However, my question is post-era, after Classes were introduced.

Comment: Because not everything warrants a class. For example, a hashmap

Comment: JS is a multi-paradigm language. It hss OOP concepts, like classes, but their use isn't *necessary*. Also, the instances of classes are also objects...

Comment: I guess I am trying to ask whether Object Literals are still relevant, now that Classes are here.

Comment: Classes are used often if *multiple* objects of the same kind has to be created, but for a single object, a plain object is enough...

Comment: And that's also a matter of personal preference...

Comment: @Grateful Well, JAVA fully supports classes, still it has `Map<K, V>` Type. Think of an object as a  `Map<K, V>`

Comment: Ah, okay. Does using an object literal have any performance benefits over classes?

Comment: @Grateful Don't think there's any non-trivial performance impact. Readability and maintainability is mostly why classes are preferred in JS IMO

Comment: Cool............

Comment: @Grateful ... you refer to the provided example several times as *object literal*; but it is not. Actually the way your example is doing the job of glueing an object was already back in the old times the least favourable approach to go with. Initializing an object via literal notation does look like that ... `let car = { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mustang', year: 1969 };`

Comment: Thank you @PeterSeliger. But I did NOT refer to my example as being an object literal. My question kind of progressed on to asking about object literals. That's all.

Comment: @Grateful 1/2 The traditional ways were more about either A) using a constructor function or B) make use of another kind of factory function that creates an object via literal notation and/or via (additional) glue code. - However, in order to answer your question one should ask oneself following questions. Who is going to build and/or maintain the code base for the application's type/object system? One Person or a team? In terms of team, which skillset do developers bring to the table? Are they capable of discussing this matter amongst each other and are they willing to agree on one solution?

Comment: @Grateful 2/2 Either approach is valid, one might even mix `Object.defineProperty` syntax into both approaches, either into the *class / constructor* or the *factory / object create* based one.